# Omnet++ IDE not opening

Tags: omnet++

when opening omnet++ it gave a "package is damaged cannot open" alert. Therefore I reinstalled it and used the installguide.pdf given by omnet++. It got rid of the alert but now closes immediately without any notification.

I installed omnetpp-5.6.2 with macOS Big Sur version 11.1. I also tried older versions, same error.
Any idea what I could try? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recent versions of macOS are getting more and more picky about unsigned executables downloaded directly from the internet. It could be that the execution is denied because of that, however your question is not specific enough as it does not state whether this occurred when you start the configuration, or during building the simulator or when running the IDE.

Temporarily you can turn off the developer identification. See this article:
See [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/205393/gatekeeper-101-why-your-mac-only-allows-apple-approved-software-by-default/#:%7E:text=To%20open%20an%20unsigned%20app%2C%20you%20need%20to%20right%2Dclick,with%20a%20valid%20developer%20signature.) article. On long term, OMNeT++ distros should be signed.

ps: I'M also assuming that you are running on an Inter processor based machine. (arm macs can also run omnet, but there is some trickery to do before that is possible)